# How to remove the serviceWorker property from the navigator object?

Tags: javascript, navigator, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Is there any way to completely remove the `serviceWorker` property from the navigator object? (So that the expression `('serviceWorker' in navigator)` is false.)

`delete` doesn't work:

```
delete navigator.serviceWorker;
'serviceWorker' in navigator; // true
```

Assigning to `undefined` doesn't do anything (even if it were sufficient):

```
navigator.serviceWorker = null;
'serviceWorker' in navigator; // true
navigator.serviceWorker === null; // false
```

`Object.defineProperty` also doesn't work:

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, "serviceWorker", { 
  configurable: true,
  value: undefined
});
'serviceWorker' in navigator; // true
navigator.serviceWorker === undefined; // true
```

(The reason to do this is to make newer browsers behave more like older browsers for testing, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make new browsers behave like older browsers for testing, you can define and use a new function:

```
function areServiceWorkersSupported() {
  return 'serviceWorker' in navigator;
}
```

And then, during tests, you can overwrite the function.

Comment: I was kinda hoping that it would be possible to remove a bunch of features at once via something like the opposite of a polyfill, which would make it possible to do quick tests with minimal changes to code. `delete window.fetch` does work, but getting rid of some of the other features seems difficult/impossible.

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.serviceWorker` is a read-only property therefore is unchangeable 
check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/serviceWorker)

Comment: Curiously, it *is* settable via `Object.*` methods--you can set the property to whatever you want, you just can't remove it.